# MeteorJS On Watch OS

Tags: android, ios, meteor, wear-os, watchkit

Is it possible to get a MeteorJS app onto a watch OS?

I'm asking related to either Apples or the Android version. After googling around, I think the android version can support a browser, but the apple watch doesn't (at least not if you don't jailbreak it).

It seems meteor works with browser functionality inside a native app wrapper. Is such a thing available for these watch OS's?

Answer (score 3):

There are some efforts to enable iOS/OSX applications to easily connect to and communicate with Meteor servers. WatchOS runs an environment that is relatively similar to iOS and so I expect that some if not all of the libraries/extensions will work in WatchOS projects. The most popular effort that I've seen is called ObjectiveDDP: https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP

ObjectiveDDP allows you to do the following:

- Connect to and authenticate with a Meteor server.
- Listen for update events on collections.
- Call Meteor Methods.
- Send CRUD commands to Meteor for a collection/document.

Comment: I was hoping something a little more native. Something like a standalone app that runs the client and server on the device itself. Completely independent of a network.

Comment: I'm sure if you jailbroke an iDevice and was able to V8/Node.js up and running, and also had a browser instance that could talk to localhost and a port, then you could run Meteor on an iDevice. To my knowledge, that's not something someone has done before. I could, however, be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As for android, the answer is no right now (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html):

> Wearable apps can access much of the standard Android APIs, but don't
>   support the following APIs:
>
> - android.webkit
> - ...

Hence, you cannot have a webview on an adroid-wear watch, which is what phonegap/cordova use to run meteor apps on android. Until that changes, I don't think it will be possible to "just run" meteor apps on an android-wear watch without writing your own native android app. As Patrick said, such a native app could still communicate with the meteor server using DDP, but it's not as straightforward as writing a meteor app that runs on regular android.